# Redirect from and alias the same url using mod_rewrite and apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Basically, I'm hosting a static HTML site and I need:

1. `http://example.com/some-direcory/index.html`
   to be redirected to:
   `http://example.com/some-direcory`
2. While still having the physical file representing that content stored at:
   `http://example.com/some-direcory/index.html`

Here's what I have:

```
# rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file/index.html
RewriteRule ^([\w\/-]+)(\?.*)?$ $1/index.html$2 [L,T=application/x-httpd-html]
```

This seems to work well for my #2 needs above, and then I have this which accomplishes my needs for #1:

```
# rewrite /dir/file/index.html to /dir/file
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,C]
```

However, when I combine these two rules obviously they create a redirect loop.  Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: you change the directory level so relative paths in index.html won't work

Comment: "`http://example.com/some-direcory`" - To clarify, you specifically want the directory to be without the trailing slash?

Comment: yes thats correct, without the slash.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond "%{THE_REQUEST}" "\s(/[\w/-]+?)/index\.html[?\s]"
RewriteRule "^" "%1" [R=301,L,C]

RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html" -f
RewriteRule "^([\w/-]+[^/])$" "/$1/index.html" [L,T=application/x-httpd-html]
```

Note the [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) possible issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I'ms till having problems with the trailing slash, I would like to have the url like this: http://example.com/some-direcory with no trailing slash.  I'm trying to adapt this but have had no luck so far.

Comment: @math0ne did you try `DirectorySlash Off` ?

Comment: I did, it just seems to give me permissions denied then.